# RaspberryPi 4 Python Send MMS Using SIM900

Tags: python, mms, raspberry-pi4, sim900

I am trying to send an MMS message using this code and it is not working.
I've used some code to send the SMS and that works, it's just the MMS.

The APN settings are fine, I've checked.
Maybe adding some output would help me figure out the problem but i don't know how and where to add that.

I've search the internet but I have found nothing.

Here's my code:

```
import binascii

import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO      
import time
    

def img_to_hex():
    with open("/home/pi/Desktop/imagee.jpg", 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
        
    img_hex = binascii.hexlify(content)
    
    return img_hex
        

def send_mms():
    phone = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
    dataphoto = img_to_hex()

    phone.write('AT\r\n')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSINIT\r\n')
    time.sleep(2)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSCURL=\"mmsdebitel\"\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSCID=1\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSPROTO=\"10.143.156.003\",8080\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSSENDCFG=6,3,0,0,2,4,1,0\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"mmsdebitel\"\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+SAPBR=1,1\r')
    time.sleep(4)

    phone.write('AT+SAPBR=2,1\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSEDIT=1\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSDOWN=\"PIC\",6307,20000,\"imagee.jpg\"\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write(dataphoto)
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSRECP=\"+mynumber\"\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSVIEW\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSSEND\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSEDIT=0\r')
    time.sleep(1)

    phone.write('AT+CMMSTERM\r')
    time.sleep(1)


send_mms()
```

Comment: You should definitely read and parse the AT command responses: probably one of them returned error, and that's why the following commands don't work.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni do you happen to have the code to parse the response by any chance ? Also, I might have figured that it is not sending due to firmware version (which I will be updating tomorrow uppon receival of the USB ttl converter).